# Observer does not work from Command but inside Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am Using Observers in Laravel to add default values to attrbiutes.

```php
public function creating($model)
{
    if (!$model->company_id) $model->company_id = (Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->company_id : null;
}
```

This works in every Controller. But if I create a custom Command in `app\Console\Commands\`. I got an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'company_id' doesn't have a default value

How do I get Observers working from Command Line?

Comment: `Auth` doesn't exist in command line, it's http middleware, so your `company_id` will always be null. The error is emitted from your database because it is empty and does not have a default value (and is likely not nullable).

Comment: Thank you @DarrylE.Clarke! If you post this as an answer I would accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth` doesn't exist in command line, it's http middleware, so your company_id will always be null. The error is emitted from your database because it is empty and does not have a default value (and is likely not nullable)